# Android SearchView widget: setIconified[ByDefault or not](false) not working

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

I have set up a `Toolbar` and within, a `SearchView` widget. The XML of this `Toolbar`'s menu is the following:

```
<item android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24px"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
```

On the fragment which has this `Toolbar`, I have overrided its method `onCreateOptionsMenu` to display the `Toolbar` and to configure `SearchView`.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menu_inflater) {
    menu_inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,menu_inflater);

    AppCompatActivity app_compat_activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    SearchView search_view = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchView).getActionView();
    search_view.setIconified(false);
    search_view.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    search_view.clearFocus();
    SearchManager search_manager = (SearchManager) Objects.requireNonNull(app_compat_activity).getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    search_view.setSearchableInfo(Objects.requireNonNull(search_manager).getSearchableInfo(app_compat_activity.getComponentName()));
}
```

My aim is that the `SearchView` expands (filling all the `Toolbar`'s width). The above code doesn't work.

Comment: remove this search_view.clearFocus(); and try

Comment: @ZaidMirza thanks for your answer. However, it didn't solve my problem: I still have to click on the icon to expand the widget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
```

to

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

Remove `search_view.clearFocus();`

Comment: It works, but why? I thought `collapseActionView|ifRoom` was censed to place the `ActionView` in the overflow menu of the `ActionBar` if no room.

Comment: You are telling system CollapseActionView and show it on toolbar if there is any space to show but your requirement was  Expand it and always show it

Comment: I have another action view in my toolbar (a burger menu, censed to be at left of the expanded search bar). If I write `app:showAsAction="always"` (or `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`), the search view expands but it hides the burger menu. Do you know if something exists to display the search view with the greatest width possible, but taking account of the other action views of the toolbar (burger menu in this case)? To be more precise, I would want to have the same toolbar than the Google Playstore (https://fscl01.fonpit.de/userfiles/7529367/image/playstore-w782.jpg

Comment: in that case instead of using Menu, make a customized Toolbar